# perl: trouble passing array to function

Tags: arrays, perl

So all i want to do is pass a an array to a function (or subroutine) in PERL

So `@Temp` contains 2 arrays
`[0] = {xx,xx,xx,xx,xx}
[1] = {xx,xx,xx,xx,xx}`

```
#returns array containing two arrays

my @temp = $lineParser->parseLine($_);

@handOne = $cardFactory->createHand(@Temp[0]);
@handTwo = $cardFactory->createHand(@Temp[1]);
```

This is the createHand method wich is contained in a seperate class (or package or whatever)

```
sub createHand
{
    my $self = shift;
    my @temp = @_;
    my @arrayOfCards;
    foreach(@temp)
    {
        my $value = substr($_,0,1);
        my $color = substr($_,1,1);

        push(@arrayOfCards,new Card($value,$color));
    }

    return @arrayOfCards;
}
```

The problem i am having is that the array gets passed but is contains  `ARRAY(XXXXX)` at the start of the array.
E.g. `{0 ARRAY(xxxxxx), 0 'xx', 1 'xx', ...}`

Why does this happen?

How can I manage to do this correctly?

Comment: Is that a typo, or do you have two variables named `@temp` and `@Temp`. Because they are two different variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn on `warnings`, you will get the following one:

```
Scalar value @Temp[0] better written as $Temp[0]
```

If you want to pass the referenced array by value, you have to dereference it:

```
@handOne = $cardFactory->createHand( @{ $Temp[0] } );
```

Comment: Thank you, seemed to fix to problem i was having.

Comment: WOuld you be able to explain what @{ $Temp[0] }  means?

Comment: Strictly speaking  `@{ $Temp[0] }` doesn't pass an array :)

Comment: @686: `$Temp[0]` is an array reference. To dereference it, you have to use the dereference operator `@{ ... }`.

Comment: alright cool thx for the reply this is the first thing i have coding in perl =D

Comment: @mpapec, how is it not an (anonymous) array?  It's not a list.  `scalar(@$aref)` returns the count of elements, where a list would not.  `f(@{[qw(foo bar baz)]})` allows `f()` to *modify* "foo", "bar", and "baz", where `f(qw(foo bar baz))` would raise a "Modification of read-only value" exception.

Comment: I wrote that dereferencing array ref doesn't pass an array which is true as `@_` doesn't have anything with `@{ $Temp[0] }` In this particular case this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub createHand
{
    my $self = shift;
    my ($temp) = @_;
    my @arrayOfCards;
    foreach(@$temp)
    {
        my $value = substr($_,0,1);
        my $color = substr($_,1,1);

        push(@arrayOfCards,new Card($value,$color));
    }

    return @arrayOfCards;
}
```

Also take note that @temp[0] is array slice in case where scalar (array ref) is wanted, so it's better to state right intention:

```
@handOne = $cardFactory->createHand($temp[0]);
```

Comment: You have two options, passing an `array` or `list of values` to function. Above example passes an array as you stated in question subject.

Comment: @{ $Temp[0] } solved my problem and $Temp[0] doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a reference instead of a value.

```
my @temp = $lineParser->parseLine($_);

@handOne = $cardFactory->createHand($Temp[0]);
@handTwo = $cardFactory->createHand($Temp[1]);
```

so in a nutshell change `@temp[0]` to `$temp[0]` when passing the argument